# How to convert a MS SQL Merge Query to work with MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

We have an SQL DB with 2 Tables and have an MS SQL `MERGE` query that works great...but...

We are hoping to move to MySQL (a more portable solution) and can't find solid documentation on how to get our SQL `MERGE` query converted to MySQL...?

Here's the MS SQL query:

```
MERGE [UpcomingEvents] Ue
USING [MCList] MC
ON Ue.post_title = MC.post_title
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET Ue.sku_crmid = MC.sku_crmid
```

I know we have to drop the `[ ]`...but we still can't get it to work...

Any ideas?

Comment: So what have you tried in MySQL so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point in using MERGE in the first place since you are only performing UPDATES... there is no INSERT when not matched in the code you provided.  If this is truly UPDATE only you could use something like the following (untested)...

```
UPDATE UpcomingEvents as Ue
   INNER JOIN MCList AS MC ON (Ue.post_title = MC.post_title)
   SET Ue.sku_crmid = MC.sku_crmid
```

Comment: Have to play around with this a bit more...but seems to do the trick! ~Thanks~